# In Mac Chrome, how can I return focus from the address bar to the page?

Tags: mac, google-chrome

I can press Cmd-L to get to the address bar, but I can't find a keystroke to bring me back to the page.  It sounds like Esc works on Windows, but it doesn't work on the Mac.  Is there an equivalent?

Comment: How about 2x Tab?

Comment: Under what conditions would you like to leave the address bar without pressing *return*?

Comment: @fideli: If you change your mind, for example.

Comment: Tab works on Windows, Esc doesn't.

Comment: @fideli: I often go to the address bar to copy the URL, then want to get back to the page.  Most commonly I want to grab a Gmail URL to send to OmniFocus, then go back to interacting with Gmail with the keyboard.

Comment: @Daniel: Ah, I see.  That does work, if I have Full Keyboard Access off in the system Keyboard settings.  If I have it on though (which I normally do), I have to tab past all of my bookmarks.  Post that as an answer: I'll accept it if no one comes up with anything better.

Comment: @Peeja: Makes sense now. Not the answer to your question, but it appears that the latest beta for Chrome [uses the OmniFocus clipping service](http://twitter.com/mikepinkerton/status/989505947435008#).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This question is also asked separately, and another highly upvoted answer is given here: https://superuser.com/a/324267/54335 which relies on creating a new search engine with a short keyword.

Answer (score 28):

How about this method using the browser's search:

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> (search)
2. Input any single character into -- might as well search for an <kbd>F</kbd> on the page since your finger is already there
3. Hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> taking you to the first search result
4. <kbd>Esc</kbd> to cancel the search

It's a bit of a kludge, but it's fewer keystrokes than the tab solution proposed. With the tab solution, I have to tab over each of the Chrome extension icons and each item in my bookmarks bar before I get to the main window.

Comment: good idea, but requires - to me - too much cognitive load for that simple task.

Comment: I like this the most so far because it requires no extra configuration. There is another solution in the accepted answer's link which requires setting up custom javascript search engine entries. The Ctrl-F solution will work regardless of what computer or VM I am on.

Comment: This solution moves the current scroll position of the browser view to the first match of the single character.

Comment: Also wanted to not that this method also requires that the web page has an 'f' in it. Or at least some text so we can search a different letter.

Comment: on Mac it's enough just to press Cmd+F (search) and Esc to return focus on page. Thanks for idea

Comment: For me, the focus is just going back to the address bar after pressing Esc. (Mac os Monterey)

Comment: Thank you for making my day. Apple and Google should work together and make our life simpler.

Answer (score 4):

As per @Peeja's request, making my comment an answer:

> How about 2x Tab?

Of course, it only works without any bars between location and web page. So hide the bookmark bar using Cmd-Shift-B temporarily.

---

Another option is (ab)using the *Find* related shortcuts to be able to move the page. If you're focusing the location bar, and press Cmd-F/G, any up/down key presses are forwarded to the web page view, as long as the find widget is open.

---

Unfortunately, neither the Chrome scripting dictionary nor the [Chrome help](http://www.google.com/support/chrome/bin/static.py?page=guide.cs&guide=25799&topic=28651) were particularly useful.

You *can* (in theory) execute JavaScript via

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    tell window 1
        tell tab 1
            execute javascript "window.document.focus();"
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

But it doesn't work as expected.

---

You can use Typinator or a similar tool and create a hotkey that enters `javascript:`<kbd>enter</kbd>. This will "leave" the location bar by entering an empty javascript command.

Comment: My final solution: Shift-Tab four times.  That tabs backwards past the four navigation buttons to the left of the address bar and back to the page.  I bound this to a keyboard shortcut with Butler.  (Typinator would work too.)  Unfortunately, there's no way to make it only work in the right context: if I press it when the address bar isn't focused all sorts of things could happen.  But it'll do.  Thanks for the ideas and the thorough research!

Comment: That doesn't work if you have extensions. Tab tabs through those first.

Comment: @Peeja definitely not a solution if you have a bookmark bar with a lot of bookmarks. It will focus each one before focusing the document!

Comment: My Chrome doesn't. The bookmarks all come *after* the address bar in the tab order, not before.