# Google Chrome (Mac) set keyboard focus from address bar back to page

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm using the latest Google Chrome (14.0.835.35) on a Mac (10.6.8)

There are quite often instances where the address bar has focus and I'd like to get back to the main page (so I can use arrow keys and all my Vimium shortcuts) without having to use the mouse and manually clicking somewhere on the page... (pressing Escape would be the obvious shortcut but it doesn't work)

Is there a way round this?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10981973/keyboard-shortcut-to-switch-focus-from-web-developer-tools-to-page-in-chrome

Answer (score 88, accepted):

This has annoyed me very much too. Using tab is not always desirable, for example when you're reading a large document. Tab could move away from where you were reading to the first link on the page.

I have found a work-around for the missing hotkey inspired by some of the answers from here: [In Mac Chrome, how can I return focus from the address bar to the page?](https://superuser.com/questions/214653/in-mac-chrome-how-can-i-return-focus-from-the-address-bar-to-the-page)

Typing "javascript:" (without quotes) and then enter will move focus back to the page. OK, so that's one solution. That's however not very nice as you would have to do a lot of typing. Now what you can do is add a new search engine with a short keyword, like "u", and set the search string to be "javascript:". Then you can type in "u" and then enter to move focus back to the page without jumping around.

Edit: Apparently this still gets upvotes. If this really bothers you please let the chrome devs know here: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=92885

Comment: Thanks for this (& sorry for delay in acknowledging.) I've used 'j' as my shortcut.

Comment: Also see this issue on vimium: https://github.com/philc/vimium/issues/226

Comment: It's 2014... is there really still not a "right way" of doing this on OS X Chrome?

Comment: On the bug page you linked: "Only users with EditIssue permission may comment". Woot!

Comment: Such a shame there's no native way of doing such a basic thing. Thanks for the workaround, it works nicely. I've assigned the javascript: search engine to the "l" (lower case L), so I can jump from Developer Tools to the page with "cmd+l l enter".

Comment: Nice workaround, although it feels a little wrong but I have set it up because this irritates me all the time as I lose access to vimium constantly.

Comment: Weirdly enough, if I actually type `javascript:` into the address bar, it Googles that query. _However_, if I add a search engine `javascript:` as the `Query URL`, it works correctly.

Comment: Weirdly for me, if I type `javascript:` in the address bar, I get a Google query for that string. However, if I add a search engine as described, then typing the keyword (`u`) and hitting enter tries to load the url `http://javascript/` which is obviously invalid and results in an error page. This is on Chrome 91.0.4472.114

Comment: Follow up to above comment: apparently the first time I saved the custom search engine, it saved it as `http://javascript:`. I just now edited it in the list of search engines to remove `http://` and it works correctly now. Thanks, @ReyCharles!

Comment: Adding `javascript:` as a search engine works beautifully! This had been bothering me for very long, but lately my workflow changed such that I started hitting this more often, so decided to finally look for a solution and I am glad that Google got me to this post quickly.

Comment: The simplest workaround is to use ⌘+F then press Escape button, the focus is back on the body. See the answer by mcint: https://superuser.com/a/1690289/26006

Answer (score 11):

On Windows at least, I've been using <kbd>F6</kbd> to switch between the URL bar and the rest of the page, also for the purpose of using Vimium. I am not sure if this works on OSX or Linux.

<kbd>F6</kbd> [cycles between keyboard accessible panes](https://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=157179) such as the URL bar, bookmarks, the page itself, and downloads. I generally keep downloads and bookmarks hidden, so <kbd>F6</kbd> acts as a toggle. It's not nearly as clean of a solution as a dedicated "focus to the page" button would be, but I've found it workable.

Comment: Does nothing in OS X.

Comment: Doesn't work for me on Windows 7 64 bit using Chrome 17.0.963.78 m. Where did you find out about this?

Comment: @PeterNore Works great for me on Windows 7 64-bit, although at the moment I'm running Chromium 19.0.1043.0. I don't remember where I first read it, but I [was able to find it on Google just now](https://www.google.com/search?q=chrome%20keyboard%20shortcut%20focus%20page). Looks like it cycles between bookmarks and downloads too, but I apparently have those hidden.

Comment: Seems to be working for me today - strange!

Comment: Doesn't seem to work on Linux, although I can get to my bookmark bar this way.

Comment: Shift-F6 works better.  Pressing F6 moves the focus to the bookmark toolbar, if it is enabled.  (This is about Windows only.)

Comment: This worked for me on Firefox on Linux, using F6.

Answer (score 4):

The best way for me is never using Chrome's URL bar, and always use Vimium's open URL hotkey, which is O by default.

Answer (score 4):

I'm using <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd>.

I mapped <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> so now I focus on the address bar with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> and unfocus with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>.

---

I'm using Ubuntu so I've mapped those keys with [autokey](https://github.com/autokey/autokey/)

Comment: Works even without mapping keys. Since F6 is address bar focus shortcut. Seems Shift+F6 do the backwards.

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way is <kbd>⌘ (Command)</kbd>+<kbd>, (comma)</kbd>,
then <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd>. 
It will open "chrome://settings/" and then close it. 
And the focus will get back to your page.

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>

<kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>Down</kbd>

P.S. :-) might not work as I don't have any Mac and had to ask a friend to test this :-)

Comment: This works!!! ⌘ + Option + Up focuses the page quicker

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>p</kbd>, then <kbd>ESC</kbd>.

This will set the focus to the webpage.

Comment: it works, but it does take a few seconds... But it's the most consistent one for me either way

Answer (score 2):

Summarizing suggestions on the page, and normalizing them into a table for easy reading and comparision:

| Action | Normal role | Note | Kind |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, then <kbd>Esc</kbd> | Find in page | Fast / light incidental work for the browser | Key combo |
| <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>, then <kbd>Esc</kbd> | Print |  | Key combo |
| <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> / <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> | Open settings & close |  | Key combo |
| in url (<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>): `javascript:`+<kbd>Enter</kbd> | Script execution | Fast / light incidental work for the browser. Also try: a search alias. Add search engine, e.g. keyword `:u`, search url `javascript:` at `about:settings/searchEngines` | Browser scripting |
| <kbd>F6</kbd> | Cycle between Accessibility Panes (Focusable Areas) | Direct & intended use of keyboard shortcut. May require repeated use for desired selection. (Windows, not macOS) | Key combo |

macOS Accessibility settings used to support a select better all fields, I don't see where it is now.

Comment: The simplest workaround is to use ⌘+F then press Escape button, the focus is back on the body.

Answer (score 0):

not a true "focus to the page" hot-key solution, but works as needed on both firefox and chrome:

use "ctrl+l" to move focus to address bar, then hit "enter".  page will reload with focus given to page.

Answer (score 0):

If using Windows, the following AHK script will do the job:

```
#IfWinActive ahk_exe chrome.exe
  !a::Send +{F6}
#IfWinActive
```

To verify:

- Focus Chrome address bar.
- Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>.
- Now the webpage should be focused.

Answer (score 0):

The best way I've found is using a hotkey-triggered [Keyboard Maestro macro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HkTcV.png) that simulates a mouse click on the bottom-left corner of the window.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to save `javascript:` as a bookmarklet and activating using a hotkey. This works instantaneously without having to have windows and things opening and closing (as required by some other solutions).

1. In a chromium browser's bookmarks manager add bookmark to bookmarks bar with url `javascript:`. I saved it under the name 'Bookmarklet - Focus Webpage'.
2. Bind to hotkey that activate bookmark from the menu bar (Bookmarks->Bookmarklet - Focus Webpage). I tried using the built-in keyboard shortcuts via system settings but could not get it to work. I'm personally using Keyboard Maestro but I'm sure there are numerous other ways. for e.g. activating the menubar item via applescript and binding to hotkey through appleshortcuts, fastscripts, etc.

Answer (score -1):

You can overcome a lot of chrome omnibar limitations with Fauxbar extension. It allows you to open a pop-up addressbar which you can close with escape key. That is besides the fact that it uses firefox algorithm for url lookup, which is awesome and WAY more usable then what omnibar offers.