# How to move focus back to the webpage in Firefox?

Tags: firefox

When the focus is in some other places in Firefox, such as the address bar, what keyboard shortcut I can use to move the focus back to the webpage (so I can use shortcuts like `Page Down` to navigate the page)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### What keyboard shortcut can I use to move the focus back to the webpage?

> <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> , then press <kbd>Tab</kbd> twice (or
>   three times):
>
> Get "focus" on webpage for in-page keyboard navigation. Note the dotted frame around the page.

Source [82 Shortcuts for Firefox (Windows)](https://shortcutworld.com/Firefox/win/Firefox_Shortcuts)

Comment: Or may be one time for Firefox 57 with only one unified address and search box?

Comment: @xuhdev Possibly. I'm running v56. First tab goes to the tab bar, second to the page context.

Answer (score 27):

The answer depends on whether you typically have a sidebar open. tl;dr:

- <kbd>Tab</kbd> (if no sidebar is open, or if sidebar is on the right)
- <kbd>F6</kbd><kbd>F6</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>F6</kbd> (if sidebar is on the left)
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> and then <kbd>Escape</kbd> (works regardless of sidebar position, avoids problem with page scroll position jumping around)
- The `javascript:` shortcut hack from this answer also works in Firefox: https://superuser.com/a/324267/143467

In Firefox 57 the search bar is gone by default. If you do not have a sidebar open then pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> once returns focus from the address bar to page content (as @DavidPostell and @xuhdev suggested in the other answer). But using <kbd>Tab</kbd> often has a side-effect of causing the page scroll position to jump around.

<kbd>F6</kbd> (Move to Next Frame) also works. I had hoped that <kbd>F6</kbd> would avoid making the page jump around, but it turns out that is not the case.

If you use a sidebar then things are more complicated. I usually have the Tree Style Tabs sidebar open, and I have to press <kbd>Tab</kbd> four times to get focus back to the page content. I can press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> twice, but that has a side-effect of scrolling the page to the bottom. On the other hand, pressing <kbd>F6</kbd> twice reliably cycles to the sidebar and then to the page.

You can move the sidebar to the right side of the browser to change the order of elements/frames that <kbd>F6</kbd> and <kbd>Tab</kbd> cycle through. If the sidebar is on the right, then pressing <kbd>F6</kbd> or <kbd>Tab</kbd> once moves focus from the location bar to the page, just as if there were no sidebar open.

My ideal would be to customize Firefox so that pressing <kbd>Escape</kbd> moves focus to the page. But I have not found a way to do that.

Answer (score 4):

If you toggle the left-side panel for history or bookmarks, the focus shifts back to the webpage, i.e., <Ctrl+B><Ctrl+B> or <Ctrl+H><Ctrl+H>

Comment: most ergonomic shortcuts among those proposed imho

Answer (score 3):

Like in Chrome ([found here](https://superuser.com/questions/324266/google-chrome-mac-set-keyboard-focus-from-address-bar-back-to-page)) you can set a favorite in Firefox to be the web address of:

`javascript:`

And if you hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> on `javascript:` in the URL bar, it'll return focus back to the page. I added a tag 'u' and keyword 'u' so that it brings up the bookmark.

Here's what I did:

bookmarks > right-click > add bookmark:

name: `u`

url: `javascript:`

tags: `u`

keyword: `u`

as @jesse hallett mentioned escape would be ideal. or a way to customize this (`fj` anyone?)?

Comment: I've been using this trick for years in Chrome and later in Brave. Recently had to start using Firefox more. What I hate about it, that in Chrome (if you're in the address bar) when pressing `u` (as in your example), it would simply move the focus back to the page without affecting the URL in the bar. In Firefox, it also changes the address to "javascript:"

Answer (score 1):

At the time I'm writing this answer, <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>F6</kbd> works on Chrome and Firefox with Windows.

Comment: Is there any point in repeating an existing answer?  Please read the help on how to answer questions.