# How can I add JavaScript to my URL as a parameter?

Tags: google-chrome, javascript

I saw it mentioned here: [Google Chrome (Mac) set keyboard focus from address bar back to page](https://superuser.com/questions/324266/google-chrome-mac-set-keyboard-focus-from-address-bar-back-to-page/324267#324267)

One way to get around not being able to move the focus from the search bar was to add JavaScript as a parameter to the search URL. I was trying to ask in the comments on the aforementioned page, but I'm not allowed to put in comments yet.

How do I do this?

Thank you!

Comment: I see the referenced post is for a Mac, which I am not on, but I believe that, say your URL is "https://www.superuser.com" you want to put your cursor in front of the URL and type so that you end up with "javascript:https://www.superuser.com" So click the address bar, press left arrow until cursor is at the very beginning of the URL, type "javascript:" and hit enter. Is this what you're looking to do? Edit: I see that the full URL is being converted to hyperlink so let me iterate that the "javascript:" must precede the entire URL including "https://" and "www."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. URL is in focus:
   [image: url in focus]
2. Press the left arrow key until your cursor precedes the **entire** url (including the HTTP and www).
   [image: cursor at beginning of URL]
3. Type "javascript:"
   [image: "javascript:" typed]
4. Press enter.
5. The focus should have returned to the webpage.

Comment: Looks like this is exactly what I am looking for! It's not showing my upvote on the solution since my acct is new, but I really appreciate you helping me out with this!